# Identifying the form in continuity and limits

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

So the Question is

$\text {If} $ $ p\neq q \neq 0$ $\text {then function}$ $f(x)$ $=$
$\frac{{(p729+x)}^{1/7}-3}{{(729+qx)}^{1/3}-9}$
$\text {is continuous at x $=$ 0}$ $\text {Prove that 63q$f(0$)$p^2$=0}$

I am facing problem in figuring out the form of this question the official solution doesn't give any hint and has just written it  must be $\frac 00$ form ,How can I figure out the form? Thanks:)

Comment: are you sure you've typed it right?

Comment: @MandarAjinthekar I guess yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=\frac{{(p729+x)}^{1/7}-3}{{(729+qx)}^{1/3}-9};\,p\ne q \ne0\tag1$$

The function is continuous at $x=0$. Therefore,
$$f(0)=\lim_{x\to0}f(x)\tag2$$

Now, we can see as $x\to0$, the denominator $\to0$. As the limit exsists at $x=0$ it has to be an indeterminate form of limits. So, obvious choice is $\frac{0}0$ form.

Hence, at $x=0$,
$$(p729+0)^{1/7}-3=0 \implies p=\frac{3^7}{729}=3$$

Calulate the limit,
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{{(p729+x)}^{1/7}-3}{{(729+qx)}^{1/3}-9}
{=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{3 (q x + 729)^{2/3}}{7 q (729 p + x)^{6/7}}\quad (\text{By L'Hospital's rule})\\=\frac{3 (729)^{2/3}}{7 q (729 p)^{6/7}}\\
=\frac{3 (3^6)^{2/3}}{7 q (3^6 \cdot3)^{6/7}}\quad(\because p=3)\\
=\frac{1}{21q}}$$

$$\therefore \lim_{x\to0}f(x)=\frac{1}{21q}\tag3$$

From $(2)$ and $(3)$,
$$f(0)=\frac{1}{21q}\ne0$$

Clearly, $63qf(0)p^2\ne0\quad(\because p\ne q \ne0 \text{ and } f(0)\ne0)$

Comment: @O M Got it ! thanks alot

Comment: @πααρτθ Σαρθι you are welcome.